# How does Require.js work with Backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, underscore.js

I am new to backbone.js, underscore.js and require.js. I tried to do a research about it a week ago, to my view, I think underscore.js is similar to usage of `<% %>` in asp.net , while we want to display any value of asp.net in html, is it correct? And about require.js, I have no idea what is the necessary between using it and without it in backbone project. I ask my college, they said that, using require.js to avoid including or loading the same javascript source in different file in the same project.

Any idea about it please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please take a look at this tutorial, is well explained and goes to the details of using backbone + require

http://backbonetutorials.com/organizing-backbone-using-modules/